# How can I setText to TextViews created in cycle?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I created a cycle to make a Layout with a TextView for every unit in an Array:

```
        for(int x = 0; x<coffeeSets.length; x++) {


        final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_list, container);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv.setText(coffeeSets[x].name);
        tv2.setText(coffeeSets[x].price + "\u20BD");
    }
```

Here is the xml of the custom layout, if that matters:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that it creates as many Layouts as I need, but it can only set the text for the first one:

[The first layout gets the text of the last, and the last one gets empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYxJo.png)

I understand that it because tv and tv2 are set to be 1st layout's textview, but how can I set text to other ones?

Comment: 1. You should add the view to you inflated view, not **this.findViewById**. 2. Where you are going add this inflate layout..? without adding into any layout, this inflated view will not visible to the user.

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran 1. yeah I've already changed it to view.findViewById.      2. it is added to container which is resolved above in code (final LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);)

     
It is visible and all fine (screenshot is in post), but setText method changes text only in the first created layout - that's the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `inflate(R.layout.custom_list, container, false)`  and add the layout(`container.addView(view);`) manually, to appear on the screen. check below code.

The reason is if you set it to true or if you give only that layout it will be attached to the parent layout immediately, you cant add multiple items again because that view will already be added. For more detail about Inflator, you can read [this article](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/)

```
final LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

for(int x = 0; x<coffeeSets.length; x++) {


    final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_list, container, false); // we can set attachToRoot as false  
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    tv.setText(coffeeSets[x].name);
    tv2.setText(coffeeSets[x].price + "\u20BD");

    container.addView(view); // this you missed 
}
```